# How can I make a command that activates when a certain entity has been destroyed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map where you go around destroying ender crystals.  When you destroy an ender crystal, I want a command block chain to activate.  Each individual crystal has a different command block chain.

But I don't want any redstone right next to a crystal.  Is there some command I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a repeat command block at the somewhere near to your chain with this command:

```
/testfor @e[type=EnderCrystal,x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=0]
```

- use the EnderCrystal's coords instead of `X`,`Y`,`Z`.

And then, at the beginning of your chain, place a repeat command block that tests for a negative output from the 1st one:

```
/testforblock X2 Y2 Z2 minecraft:command_block -1 {SuccessCount:0}
```

- use the 1st command block's coords instead of `X2`, `Y2`, `Z2`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing this. One is easy, but has the potential to bug out. The other is a lot more complicated but can be done.

First off, you can use a testfor command to check for the endercrystal, and run a repeater from the command block directly into a NOT-gate. Be aware that redstone isn't always the most stable thing. I've had this setup bug out on me in the spawn chunks of a Spigot server before, so it carries the potential to stop working until the redstone is updated.

The second method involves using a command block to test for the entities, then setting the output to an objective through the [/stats](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Command_stats) command. When the objective reaches zero, you can activate your command blocks.